# Test just hangs when I call page.driver .render (using phantomjs, capybara and poltgergeist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, phantomjs, testunit, poltergeist

I'm getting frustrated with this issue.. I have a Test::Unit test.. using Capybara + Poltergeist + PhantomJS.. trying to take a screenshot..

But when I call it..

```
        page.driver.render "screenshot.png"
```

It just hangs..

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you included `Capybara::DSL` ?

Comment: Yes, I have it, it just hangs on the page.driver.render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I had to go with just the Selenium Web driver, and these specific versions, it seems they are out of sync at some point and capybara/its wrapper won't be able to communicate with the driver underneath and therefore Phantom, as a consequence, is not accessible.

This configuration worked for me:

> gem 'capybara', '1.1.4'
>
> gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.27.2'

Answer (score 0):

Try being more specific.  The following puts it in a temp folder, makes sure that it exists, puts it in there, and then opens it when it's ready.

```
  dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache/capybara"
  file = "#{dir}/#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}.png"
  FileUtils.mkdir_p dir
  page.driver.render file
  wait_until { File.exists?(file) }
  system "open #{file}"
```